# Converting m4a -> mp3 on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ffmpeg, mp3, m4a

I currently post mp3s to a site and stream it to users. However, I record in m4a and that doesn't stream unless you use flash or some special html5 implementations.

I'd like to be able to upload m4as to the site and have it converted to mp3.

There are a few implementations that wrap ffmpeg for .net, but few have any documentation (FFLIB.NET, FFmpeg.NET, FFMpeg-sharp), especially with non-video formats.

Does anyone have any ideas about tackling this issue, or maybe some alternatives? I don't believe my host (Arvixe) supports Python on its ASP.NET packages...

**EDIT**: I selected Jorge's answer as, with the comments as further context, it mostly answers my question.

Comment: AAC (m4a) can stream just like mp3 can. It depends on the transport container and the client. What client are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was already a discussion about that, your code can easily run even if asp.net was not mentioned, because in the end, asp.net is only on top of the .net framework.

[How do I convert an M4A file to an MP3 or WMA file programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144466/how-do-i-convert-an-m4a-file-to-an-mp3-or-wma-file-programmatically)

hope it helps,

Comment: I feel like all the existing posts just batch out an executable. They aren't actually making use of any library or anything.

Comment: @Killnine yeah, I've seen that also, but the problem is that neither of those formats are free, in fact you have to pay royalties to both of them, so unless you find a commercial one, you're out of luck :-/

Comment: So, presumably, the only option is to upload ffmpeg to my asp.net site, chmod it, and make calls to it behind the scenes?

Comment: yeah, seems fair, in fact, if you think about it, that process might be lengthy, probably you can make a queue to receive all the encoding requests and then a Converter Service will take care of it and copy the results to a folder or do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: One last thing: I originally thought I needed to convert this because AAC didn't appear to be streaming. However, I just needed to add .m4a as a MIME type to my Apache configuration! see: http://jehiah.cz/a/teach-apache-about-m4a-files